# use icu4c in Android Application

Tags: android

there is one "icu4c" project at android platform (external/icu4u)
any one know how to use this in my android application?
I want to do some conversion, ec. unicode->big5, ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ICU4C is the C version of the ICU library, but if you want to use the ICU functionalities in your code, use the ICU4J lib, also available on the [ICU site](http://site.icu-project.org/)